# Implement Class with Read and Write method

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, in-memory

I got one interview question:

Implement one class (named as Resources) is having two methods.

```
public class Resources {
   Read()
   Write()
}
```

We have to implement this class with following constraint.

1. parallel Read() call is possible.
2. parallel Write() call is not possible.
3. parallel Read() and Write() is not possible

I am trying to figure out, how can we implement the locking for these methods. So that for one class object, we can fulfill mentioned constraints.

Any lead would be helpful.

Comment: Use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure they are not looking for this answer. But if the internal state of 'resources' can be represented as a single variable and you make the variable volatile, then the requirements are implemented.

```
class Resources{
  private volatile int a;
  
  public int read(){return a;}

  public void write(int a){this.a=a;}
}
```

Modern processors make use some kind of MESI (MODIFIED, EXCLUSIVE, SHARED, INVALID) based cache coherence protocol. A parallel write isn't possible because only 1 CPU at a time will have the cache line containing the variable in EXCLUSIVE/MODIFIED state. If there are no writers, then multiple reading CPUs can have the cache line in SHARED state.

If they are doubting my answer, then you can send them a link to the following book which they can download for free:

https://www.morganclaypool.com/doi/abs/10.2200/S00962ED2V01Y201910CAC049

I guess they are looking for answer Burak Serder already has given in a comment to your post but a readwritelock is more complex to use and much slower compared to a volatile variable. Also the above implementation is non blocking; so no matter if a thread gets suspended, other threads can still make progress which is not the case with a lock based implementation like a read/write lock.